# Is it safe to put CSS codes in WordPress customizer?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I put some CSS codes in WordPress Customize `Appearance> Customize` in my case `Additional CSS` option, but I don't know if it is safe to put them there or not, since if the theme may get updated I afraid of losing them.

Comment: Yes its safe. if theme will be updated your custom css code will not remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add code safely to the customizer area, it's kept in place even when updating the theme. A Child Theme is nevertheless even more recommended due to the more granular control.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can add your additional css there. This is meant to be there for the same reason and your code will not be washed out even after updating your theme or plugins or wordpress until you change the theme.